# What is the overlap between Star Wars canon and Legends?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, canon

After Disney established a new canon for *Star Wars*, I've found it relatively easy to determine what is and is not canon, but I've found it a bit more difficult to do so for Legends after the fact, specifically when it comes to what material is both canon and Legends (or perhaps more precisely canon in the Disney continuity while still being canon in the Legends continuity).

Obviously, *Star Wars I-VI* (and their novelizations insofar as they don't cause contradictions) are both canon and Legends, and I know that *Clone Wars* is considered canon and Legends, but that's where it gets a bit more complicated. The *Clone Wars* movie and presumably seasons 1-6 would all be canon and Legends, but this leaves a few questions:

1. What about *Son Of Dathomir* (Dark Horse comic run from 2014 heavily related to *Clone Wars* and adopted into the canon)? I'm guessing this would be both canon and Legends.
2. What about other things published around the time of the Disney acquisition, are there works not clearly marked as Legends which fall under both continuities? *Blade Squadron* would be one example: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blade_Squadron_(short_story)
3. What about *Clone Wars* season 7 (released on Disney+ in 2020)?
4. What about other shows heavily related to *Clone Wars* characters like *Rebels*, *Bad Batch*, *Ahsoka*, etc? I'm guessing these wouldn't fall into both categories given how long after the establishment of Disney canon they were released.
5. Anything else I might be missing?

Comment: A given work (show, novel, comic, video game, etc.) cannot be both canon *and* Legends, it is either canon *or* Legends. Elements of the franchise (events, characters, etc.) may have both canon and Legends elements. Wookieepedia does a pretty good job differentiating -- it has separate canon and Legends tabs for an article that has both canon and Legends elements. Elements that are solely canon or solely Legends have a "canon" or "Legends" banner, respectively. For example, your link to the Blade Squadron short story has a canon banner and no Legends tab.

Comment: "canon in the Legends continuity" is a contradiction in terms: Legends is by definition not canon.

Comment: Wookiepedia seems to be the answer to most canon vs Legends questions, isn't it? You can switch between the tabs, or go looking for something and see in which section it falls. But of course, it's a "community" wiki and it could have errors...

Comment: @Null: I don't think that's *entirely* fair. The Legends continuity is certainly expansive, but even it does not include things such as a random fanfic that somebody uploaded to the internet without Lucasfilm's permission. So Legends has its own canon, which should not be confused with the Canon continuity. (As you can tell, I'm not entirely thrilled with Lucasfilm's terminology here, but oh well.)

Comment: @Kevin - Legends means 'licensed', but not necessarily conforming to any particular canon. Some Legends things are canon to other works by the same author, etc. Others stand alone

Comment: @Null - I agree that the canon/legends tabs are very useful, but it doesn't always give a comprehensive view of what was considered canon before the acquisition. For example, each of the original 6 movie pages on Wookieepedia only have a canon tab, but that obviously doesn't mean that they aren't present in the legends continuity.

Comment: @Kevin In the sense that Legends is somewhat official, yes, it is a pseudo-canon that is different than random fan-fiction (it is, using the terminology given in the announcement of the term, a "banner" bestowed by Disney). However, it is a separate continuity from *the* canon continuity and so it is highly misleading / confusing to refer to a "canon" within Legends. The point is that anything in the Legends *continuity* is by definition not part of the canon *continuity*, and we usually omit the explicit "continuity".

Comment: @bgeorge Canon and Legends overlap, so anything canon that Legends does not contradict is part of the Legends continuity as well. The original three films are solely canon in the sense that there are no alternate elements that exist only in Legends, but of course the original three films are part of the Legends continuity. On the other hand, [*Rogue One*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story) is solely canon yet there are Legends stories, games, etc. which contradict it, so *Rogue One* itself is not part of the Legends continuity (similar for the prequel trilogy).

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand the close votes - the numbered list seems more like examples of edge cases than a list of separate questions. The question "which works are in both continuities?" is fully answerable.

Comment: @Null AFAIK the "anything canon that doesn't contradict" description isn't how Lucasfilm has presented it—off the top of my head, there's nothing in _Jedi: Fallen Order_ that substantially contradicts Legends, but it would be odd to describe it as officially part of the Legends continuity. (Headcanon, sure!)

Comment: @MiloP The original trilogy (and *Jedi: Fallen Order*, etc.) are entirely canon, and Legends does not contradict such canon works. While those works don't have the Legends banner (because they are canon), it is of course necessary for them to be part of the Legends continuity -- otherwise there'd be no Battle of Yavin or Hoth, Yoda training Luke, Luke bringing Anakin back at the Battle of Endor, etc., in the Legends continuity.

Comment: @Null uh what? Jedi: Fallen Order is definitely not part of the Legends continuity. Just because it overlaps major events doesn't mean it must be part of that continuity. I'm with Milo on this one, headcanon sure, but it shouldn't be generally regarded as part of the Legends continuity.

Comment: @bgeorge Forget *Jedi: Fallen Order* and think of the Original Trilogy (they're all fully canon); now, if the Original Trilogy is not part of the Legends continuity then almost all Legends works would make no sense as they'd be missing critical events. For example, the Legends novel [*Shadows of the Empire*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shadows_of_the_Empire_(novel)) references Han Solo being frozen in carbonite -- but if Episode V is not part of the Legends continuity then how did Han Solo get frozen in carbonite? For that matter, who the heck are Han Solo, Darth Vader, etc.?

Comment: ...Canon works are not *branded* "Legends" (because they don't need the brand), but Legends builds on the events, characters, etc. of canon works...hence canon works must be part of the Legends continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, anything released starting April 25th, 2014—the date of the announcement of the [new continuity model](https://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page)—should be considered Canon unless explicitly branded as Legends. Canon also includes the numbered Star Wars films and *The Clone Wars*:

> While Lucasfilm always strived to keep the stories created for the EU consistent with our film and television content as well as internally consistent, Lucas always made it clear that he was not beholden to the EU. He set the films he created as the canon. This includes the six Star Wars episodes, and the many hours of content he developed and produced in Star Wars: The Clone Wars. These stories are the immovable objects of Star Wars history, the characters and events to which all other tales must align.
>
> <sub>(https://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page)</sub>

As you mention, *Son of Dathomir* is apparently part of both as well, since it's based on unproduced material for TCW and has apparently been published as Legends [in some locales](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Maul%E2%80%94Son_of_Dathomir#Star_Wars_Legends); Lucasfilm's Matt Martin [appears to agree](https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/1251234974394548224).

### Definitely in both

As of time of writing, the following are all that's known to be part of both continuities:

- ***Star Wars* Episodes I - VI**
- **Novelizations of Episodes I - VI** where they don't contradict other stories
- ***The Clone Wars* film** and **seasons 1-6**
- ***Son of Dathomir***

### Gray areas

The film novelizations seem to have been largely ignored by newer canon, and the prequel novelizations in particular tend to contain a lot of references to Expanded Universe elements. I don't think Lucasfilm has explicitly said so, but from what I can tell, they only continue to be released as "Canon" to avoid making people think that the films themselves are no longer canon:

> For example, the '76 Star Wars novelization calls Luke 'Blue Five' and has him do two trench runs. But if you were to slap a Legends label on it, you'd get people assuming all the events didn't happen. Not at all helpful.
>
> [...]
>
> [And if it helps put any of this into context; this is just my opinion. I am not (and have never been) "in charge of canon" so this means nothing as far as how things were done, are done, or will continue to be done]
>
> <sub>([2021 tweets by Pablo Hidalgo](https://twitter.com/pabl0hidalgo/status/1439678385442078721))</sub>

The Fantasy Flight RPG sourcebooks have been published both before and after the Canon reset, and it isn't currently clear which (if any) continuity they're part of. Wookieepedia, for example, seems to have a [best-guess policy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wookieepedia:Canon_policy/Fantasy_Flight_Games) depending on the publication date of the source and the origin of individual elements that have appeared in stories from one continuity but not the other.

### Other cases

- *Blade Squadron* was technically published a few days before the Canon announcement (April 22nd, 2014), but was announced as being within the new Canon:

  [image: Red circle with text]

  > #### Fiction in *Insider*
  >
  > Starting with the two-part *Blade Squadron* story (published in #149 and #150), fiction in *Star Wars Insider* is a part of the new canon.
  >
  > <sub>(*Star Wars Insider* #150 [via Lightsaber Rattling](https://archive.ph/nltyu))</sub>
- There are other Canon works that started life as Expanded Universe projects (such as [*Tarkin*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel))), or are otherwise compatible with details from Legends, but they're still considered part of the Canon continuity due to their release timing and branding.
- Other works were released well after the Canon change, but were still released as Legends at time of first publication. For example, [Issue 108 of the 1977 Marvel *Star Wars* comic series](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(1977)_108) was released in 2019, five years after the new Canon announcement and 33 years after the previous issue, but is still branded as Legends.
- *The Old Republic* has also continued to receive new content, despite being firmly set in the Legends continuity. However, in recent years, some of it has been explicitly inspired by Canon material, such as *The Mandalorian*:

  [image: Game screenshots showing a character wearing Mandalorian armor, resembling the titular character from The Mandalorian]

  > Inspired by The Mandalorian, check out the newest Armor Sets, Weapons, mounts, and more, available now on the Cartel Market!
  >
  > <sub>[Cartel Market Additions: Game Update 6.1.4](https://www.swtor.com/info/news/article/20201020-0) on swtor.com</sub>

This isn't meant to imply that SWTOR takes place in Canon, however, and it's unclear to what degree in-game items are considered canonical anyway.

- Relatedly, the upcoming KOTOR remake is apparently going to remain in Legends:

  > KOTOR, which is part of Legends storytelling, dials the Star Wars clock back to over 4,000 years before the Skywalker saga.
  >
  > <sub>[Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic Strikes Back with New Remake](https://www.starwars.com/news/knights-of-the-old-republic-remake) on starwars.com</sub>
- [*Galaxy of Heroes*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Galaxy_of_Heroes) is a mobile game that includes both Legends and Canon characters, but [isn't intended to be canon for either](https://archive.vgfacts.com/thread-2875.html):

  [image: Screenshot of Galaxy of Heroes squad selection including Bastila, Yoda, Ezra, Anakin, and Old Ben]

Comment: They've ignored the novelisations because they sell like hotcakes and make bank for Lucasfilm

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Probably one of the best examples of works which were released after the canon change, but which are still released as legends would be The Old Republic expansions.

Comment: @Valorum I believe you but I cannot wrap my head around people buying *novelizations* of goddamn Star Wars movies. I mean, just watch the movies! I think... I'm getting too old for this shit.

Comment: @bgeorge Forgot about SWTOR! Updated with that and more game examples.

Comment: This reminded me how much Galaxy of Heroes sucks. My daughter is currently infatuated with SW (her daddy helped) and we installed this piece of garbage... it's barely a game at all, the same click a thousand times over upgrades and kit and stuff and then fight some half-assed battles that involve more pointless clicking and then it's over as soon as it started. The same template as most mobile "battle" games with a SW theme. "Star Wars Cow Clicker". I hate it.